# Get arrays from Array of objects using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with a lot of data (thousands), I want to get the arrays from the array of object in one object which I can use for further manipulation of the data. I'm not sure where I am messing up with.

```js
var obj = [{a: 'a', b: [{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]}, {a: 'a', b: [{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]}];
obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc.push(...cur['b']);
}, [])
```

I thought if i could use reduce to get the results, but I am unable to get it. For the first time, when reduce runs it adds the data to `acc` however on next iteration it only gives the length of previous `acc` (What is that) which causes the loop to break by throwing an error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`?

I need to efficient way to get the data be it any method that can help me.

expected o/p :

```
[{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}, {a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]
```

Comment: You need to assign the `reduce` return value to a variable. `var output = obj.reduce(..)`. And you need to `return acc` inside the callback.

Comment: Doesn't accumulator keeps the track of the last values? Do we need to explicitly do that?

Comment: That's how `reduce` works. The value returned in each loop is used in the next iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `map` job, not a `reduce` job:

```js
var obj = [{a: 'a', b: [{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]}, {a: 'a', b: [{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]}];

let result = obj.flatMap(x => x.b)

console.log(result)
```

Rule: if you need `return` in your reduce, you're using it wrong.

To elaborate: this is a very common `reduce` anti-pattern:

```
result = array.reduce((result, item) => {
    mutate result somehow
    return result
}, initialization)
```

This is a basically a loop written "inside out", and it's very unreadable: the thing that you do *first* (initialization) is at the end, there are lots of punctuation and you need the `return` statement, which is nothing but noise. A simple loop is much easier to read, not to mention more efficient:

```
result = initialization 
for (let item of array)
    mutate result
```

There's also a variation of this anti-pattern where the size of the result is equal to the size of input, e.g.

```
result = array.reduce((result, item) => {
    result.push(something)
    return result
}, [])
```

This is just `map` in disguise.

`reduce` shines when you're actually "reducing" an array to a single value, that is, when the callback is a simple immutable computation, for example:

```
sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

Comment: The accumulator accumulates callbackFn's return values. It is the accumulated value previously returned in the last invocation of the callback—or initialValue, if it was supplied (see below). - This is from Mozilla what do they say to return it? FlatMap is much better way to solve this problem though, but I need to understand this.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara: added some explanations

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from the callback. Try this

```js
var obj = [{a: 'a', b: [{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]}, {a: 'a', b: [{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]}];
console.log(obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc.push(...cur['b']);
    return acc;
}, []));
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce:

> **accumulator** The accumulator accumulates callbackFn's return values. It is the accumulated value *previously returned in the last
> invocation of the callback*—or initialValue, if it was supplied (see
> below).

Comment: Doesn't accumulator keeps the track of the last values? Do we need to explicitly return  that?

Comment: Yes, we have to return it. No, it doesn't keep track without that. You can tell by comparing the code output if the documentation doesn't convince you.

Comment: I mean it does convince me and worked, but what @georg meant by saying that ` if you need return in your reduce, you're using it wrong.` ?

Comment: I think what @georg is saying is that if you are writing code using `reduce` with an accumulator like that (using a return value to accumulate) then there are better ways of achieving a similar result. All I did was to fix the bug in your code. What he did was offer a better way of getting what you want, and he added a heuristic device for determining whether using `reduce` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return statment inside the reduce and you better use concat() instead of push() because it will return the result of concatenation not the length of the array

```
var obj = [{a: 'a', b: [{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]}, {a: 'a', b: [{a1: 'a'},{ b1: 'b'}]}];
const result = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(...cur['b']), []);
```

but i prefer georg's answer